Machine Learning Model to Predict the Type of Variable Star from Light Curve
I've created this machine learning model that predicts the type of variable star based on the light curve. A variable star is a type of star whose luminosity changes over time. My model predicts between Heartbeat stars and ECL (eclipsing variable) stars. To do this, it takes the magnitude (luminosity) and the time value (labeled HJD-2450000). It then predicts between ECL and Heartbeat star. Here's my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve, PrecisionRecallDisplay
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df = df.sample(frac=1)
# Convert columns to numeric, coercing errors to NaN
df['HJD-2450000'] = pd.to_numeric(df['HJD-2450000'], errors='coerce')
df['mag'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mag'], errors='coerce')

# Handle any NaN values if they exist
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Create binary labels
df['Type'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x.startswith('HB') else 1)

# Feature scaling
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(df[['HJD-2450000', 'mag']])

# Add polynomial features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
poly_features = poly.fit_transform(scaled_features)

# Update DataFrame with new features
df_poly = pd.DataFrame(poly_features, columns=poly.get_feature_names_out())
df_poly['Type'] = df['Type']

# Separate majority and minority classes
X = df_poly.drop('Type', axis=1)
y = df_poly['Type']

# Handle class imbalance with SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(random_state=29130)
X_resampled, y_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X, y)

# Split into train and test datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled, test_size=0.2, random_state=29130)

# Define model inputs
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],), dtype=tf.float32, name='features')

# Model architecture with regularization
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
dense_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

def create_model(my_inputs, my_outputs, my_learning_rate):
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=my_inputs, outputs=my_outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'), tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='BA')])
    return model

learning_rate = 0.001  # Use Adam optimizer with a lower learning rate
my_model = create_model(inputs, dense_output, learning_rate)

# Train the model with early stopping
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True) #change patience to 10 

def train_model(model, features, labels, epochs, batch_size):
    history = model.fit(x=features, y=labels, batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stopping])
    epochs = history.epoch
    hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
    ba = hist["BA"]
    return epochs, ba

epochs, ba = train_model(my_model, X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=64) #change epochs and batch size

# Plotting the accuracy curve
def plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, ba):
    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel("Epoch")
    plt.ylabel("Binary Accuracy")
    plt.plot(epochs, ba, label="Binary Accuracy")
    plt.legend()
    plt.ylim([ba.min()*0.94, ba.max()*1.05])
    plt.show()

plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, ba)

# Evaluate the model and plot precision-recall curve
def plot_precision_recall_curve(model, features, labels):
    # Predict probabilities
    y_scores = model.predict(features).ravel()

    # Calculate precision and recall at different thresholds
    precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(labels, y_scores)

    # Plot the precision-recall curve
    display = PrecisionRecallDisplay(precision=precision, recall=recall)
    display.plot()
    plt.title("Precision-Recall Curve")
    plt.show()

plot_precision_recall_curve(my_model, X_test, y_test)

# Evaluate the model
evaluation = my_model.evaluate(x=X_test, y=y_test, batch_size=64)
print(f"Model AUC: {evaluation[1]}")

Here are the Binary Accuracy and Precision-Recall Curves of my model:


I want to get the accuracy up to a point where it's actually useful. Are there any improvements I can make? I have a few considerations:

Something's wrong with my data. This, I think is the most likely option since I was getting good accuracy up until I realized to shuffle df. When I print df, it outputs:
My inaccurate model might be due to me not showing the relationship between magnitude (luminosity of the star) as time goes on. For context, variable stars' light curves look like this: 
The shape of the light curve can be used to classify what type of variable star the example is. But in my case, each training instance consists of a single point, with HJD-2450000 and magnitude values (time and luminosity values). If this is why my model isn't working, is there a way to have one training instance capture the whole of the variable light curve? I don't want to use image recognition, but is there a way to use cross-products or something else to capture this relation and categorize different types of graphs.
Something else that might be going on is my model isn't training at all. Is there something with my code preventing it from accessing the training data?
I also considered that something else might be needed, is there something else I need to add such as embeddings? If so, how would I add this?

Apart from these, is there anything else I can do to improve this code?

If the classes are about balanced, your model isn't doing much better than random chance.

You're asking for two very separate critiques, of ML approach and
of implemented code.
That P-R curve looks just dreadful.
It's saying that for super obvious cases you nail it,
and then after that you're basically batting zero.
I have to believe the universe has some diversity in the stars it contains,
so the curve suggests your model has failed to generalize to unseen instances.
Please remember the net offers other resources,
including https://datascience.stackexchange.com.
magic number
df['HJD-2450000'] = pd.to_numeric(df['HJD-2450000'], errors='coerce')

A bit of jargon is to be expected.
It wouldn't hurt to take a stab at explaining some of it,
especially when you seek the assistance of non-astronomer collaborators.
We appear to be talking about a
Heliocentric Julian Day
here.
You didn't describe how the df arrives at this code excerpt, fine, whatever,
one assumes this code resides within a helper function
and there's some mainline driver that calls it.
The bigger mystery is what 2_450_000 might denote,
as 6.7 millennia doesn't really ring any bells.
It would be helpful for the source code to include
a conversion function which turns those values into
datetimes,
or at least a comment that mentions an epoch of October 9th, 1995.
PyPI
has several high quality astronomy packages
that stand at the ready to do some of the code + documentation
heavy lifting for you.
Take advantage of what's available.
Certainly the - minus is evocative and helpful,
but consider turning it into an _ underscore
for convenience of access in expressions like
... = pd.to_numeric(df.HJD_2450000, errors='coerce'),
much as you can already refer to df.mag.
inplace
df.dropna(inplace=True)

The semantics of (now deprecated) inplace have proven troublesome,
and will be dropped in a future release.
Prefer to create a new dataframe:
df = df.dropna()

helpful comments
# Create binary labels
df['Type'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x.startswith('HB') else 1)

The comment could have observed that an 'HB' prefix
denotes a heartbeat variable star.
The identifier df.Type would be clearer if it focused
on eclipsing stars with a spelling of df.is_ecl.
Consider phrasing the boolean lambda as not x.startswith('HB').
scaling
This can make sense:
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(df[['HJD-2450000', 'mag']])

The OP review context didn't describe how the dataframe arrives here.
My concern is that some runs may have a subset
of valid dates and valid magnitudes.
Putting "time since start" and magnitude on similar z-scale can make sense.
But if you started with July 2024 observations from
JWST,
and a subsequent run adds August observations,
I'm concerned you'll have persisted trained models
that aren't compatible with the new observations.
Consider e.g. always including some "ancient" 2010 or even 2020 observations.
Consider always including a maximally bright and a maximally dim magnitude
in the input dataset.
Intuitively, I have a tough time seeing how putting elapsed time
and magnitude on similar scales will help things, as magnitude is f(time).
But I suppose it won't harm anything.
Wouldn't you rather use an X input feature of "magnitude variation",
something like that?
And perhaps also "period of variation"?
quadratic model for a periodic phenomenon
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)

Didn't you tell us, in the text and in the graphical light curves,
that magnitude will go up and down and up and down?
I can't imagine how a parabola would adequately model that.
Are we maybe shooting for a curve fit of just a small portion?
The code and comments don't really describe that.
Some stars have intrinsically low luminosity or are very far away.
Comparing them to bright or nearby stars doesn't make sense to me,
since "distance from earth" has no bearing on a Y of "variable star type".
OTOH scaling a given star's observations against its own observations would
make perfect sense, telling us about its variation rather than its distance.
It's possible that my understanding of these details differs from your own,
as the Review Context didn't really fill in many of the gaps.
We strive for clear communications.
Consider breaking out (some of) this code into one or more helper functions.
Consider adding a """docstring""" to each function, describing

what goes in
what the function does
what goes out

For example, such documentation could resolve doubts about whether
we're examining a timeseries for a single star versus
examining a mixture of chronologically ordered observations
of a great many stars.
SMOTE
# Handle class imbalance with SMOTE

Based on the recent literature, I can't recommend the SMOTE technique to you.
We haven't seen robust reproduction of
successes claimed by the original SMOTE authors.
Consider adopting another approach for handling class imbalance,
such as weighting.
model choice
# Model architecture with regularization

It's not obvious why this NN would be a good fit for the present use case.
The comments and Review Context offered no background or justification.
Consider exploring alternate classifier schemas, perhaps
RBF
or SVM.
If [astro]physics suggests a mechanism for the difference
between Heartbeat vs ECL stars, then definitely make that
part of your schema selection, and write down the reasoning.
For example, when predicting the battlefield trajectory of a cannonball
in a terrestrial gravity field, a quartic or even cubic model would be
a poor choice. The equations of motion tell us that (ignoring drag)
we should expect a quadratic altitude relationship.
In your Business Domain there surely should be similar
predictive relationships that we want to tell the ML model about.
hypothesis space
The light curves you depict appear to be drawn from very different
families of {functions, hypotheses}.
At least one of them looks like a rectified \$|\sin t\,|\$.
Others have different shapes, with the interesting detail
of showing roughly similar versus sharply asymmetric
attack
and decay slopes.
feature engineering
You're not extracting such details,
and therefore are not feeding them to any ML models.
Go to the trouble of computing them.
See if you can distinguish variable star types based solely on those numbers.
If you can, there's a fair chance a ML model can.
residuals
You might have three or more conjectured hypotheses, such as
rectified sine, symmetric triangle wave, and asymmetric.
You can readily compute residuals (difference from the proposed one)
and offer those as three additional feature columns.
This lets the ML model see the degree to which
a sine or some other function explains the observed data,
and can assist with generalizing to unseen observations
in the presence of noise.

You've nailed it when you said the ML side is separate from the coding style side.
